# ggplot2 missing labels after custom scaling of axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am attempting to apply a custom scaling of my x-axis using `ggplot2` and `scales::trans_new()`. However, when I do some of the axis labels go missing. Can someone help me figure out why?

Setup:

```
library(tidyverse)

# the data
ds <- tibble(
  myx = c(1, .5, .1, .01, .001, 0),
  myy = 1:6
)

# the custom transformation
forth_root_trans_rev <- scales::trans_new(
  name = "sign_fourth_root_rev",
  transform = function (x) { - abs(x)^(1/4) },
  inverse = function (x) { x^4 }
)
```

### Plot 1:

When I try and plot this the label for `x = 0` gets lost.

```
# plot - missing x-label at `0`
ggplot(ds, aes(x = myx, y = myy)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = forth_root_trans_rev,
    breaks = sort(unique(ds$myx)),
  )
```

[image: missing x-label at <code>0</code>]

### Plot 2

When I add some space on both sides of the graph, even more x-labels get lost.

```
# plot - missing x-labels below 0.5
ggplot(ds, aes(x = myx, y = myy)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = forth_root_trans_rev,
    breaks = sort(unique(ds$myx)),
    expand = expand_scale(mult = c(.1, .6))
  )
```

[image: missing x-labels below 0.5]

I presume this is related to this old issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/980. Nevertheless, I can't figure out how to apply this transformation and retain all x-labels.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... This call returns the expected values: `forth_root_trans_rev$transform(c(-2, 1, 0, 1, 2))` (`# [1] -1.189207 -1.000000  0.000000 -1.000000 -1.189207`). Though nonsensical for negative `x` - but then again the `myx` variable contains only positive values (and zero)

Comment: @Jet using the `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, 10^-6))` clips the data, so that the point at `x = 0` is not displayed, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is due to the combination of two factors:

1. Your x-axis values (after transformation) fall in the [-1, 0] range, so any expansion (whether additive or multiplicative) will nudge the final range to cover both positive and negative values.
2. Your custom transformation is not one-to-one in the `[<some negative number>, <some positive number>]` region.

**How it occurred**

Somewhere deep inside the all code used to build the ggplot object (you can run `ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot` before printing the plot & step into `layout$setup_panel_params()`, but I don't recommend this for casual users... the rabbit hole goes really deep down there), x-axis breaks are calculated in the following manner:

1. Obtain limits for the transformed values (for `c(1, .5, .1, .01, .001, 0)` in the question, this will be `(-1, 0)`).
2. Add expansion to the limits, if applicable (default expansion for a continuous axis is 5% on either side, so the limits become `(-1.05, 0.05)`).
3. Apply the inverse transformation on the limits (taking `x^4` on the limits yields `(1.215506, 0.000006)`).
4. Apply the transformation on both user-inputted breaks & limits (for breaks, `c(1, .5, .1, .01, .001, 0)` becomes `(-1.0000000, ..., 0.0000000)`, but for limits, `(1.215506, 0.000006)` now becomes `(-1.05, -0.05)`, which is **narrower** than `(-1.05, 0.05)`).
5. Breaks beyond the limit's range are dropped (since the limits now stop at -0.05, the break at 0 is dropped).

**How to get around this**

You can modify your transformation with the use of `sign()` to preserve positive / negative values, such that the transformation is one-to-one in the full range, as suggested by Hadley in the discussion on the GH issue you linked. For example:

```
# original
forth_root_trans_rev <- scales::trans_new(
  name = "sign_fourth_root_rev",
  transform = function (x) { - abs(x)^(1/4) },
  inverse = function (x) { x^4 }
)

# new
forth_root_trans_rev2 <- scales::trans_new(
  name = "sign_fourth_root_rev",
  transform = function (x) { -sign(x) * abs(x)^(1/4) },
  inverse = function (x) { -sign(x) * abs(x)^4 }
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# comparison of two transformations
# y1 shows a one-to-one mapping in either (-Inf, 0] or [0, Inf) but not both;
# y2 shows a one-to-one mapping in (-Inf, Inf)
data.frame(x = seq(-1, 1, 0.01)) %>%
  mutate(y1 = x %>% forth_root_trans_rev$transform() %>% forth_root_trans_rev$inverse(),
         y2 = x %>% forth_root_trans_rev2$transform() %>% forth_root_trans_rev2$inverse()) %>%
  gather(trans, y, -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = trans)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  facet_wrap(~trans)
```

[image: comparison plot]

**Usage**

```
p <- ggplot(ds, aes(x = myx, y = myy)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

p + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = forth_root_trans_rev2,
    breaks = sort(unique(ds$myx))
  )
p + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = forth_root_trans_rev2,
    breaks = sort(unique(ds$myx)),
    expand = expand_scale(mult = c(.1, .6)) # with different expansion factor, if desired
  )
```

[image: plots]