# ggplot new scale_x function failing to work correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

In order to get rid of non-trading days of stocks (aka weekends) in `ggplot` instead of the date, I use the number of rows in the data and then add breaks and labels. The code below "**works**" does the trick and plots the data like `chartSeries` from the quantmod package. `ggplot` adds information that is not there or shows gaps depending on what kind of chart you are making. For dealing with stock prices this is not handy. Hence the **works** section.

But since this is just a labeling issue, an axis transformer function would be more logical and easier to use. I tried creating a `scale_x_finance` function (see ***does not work*** section), but I must be interpreting the inverse function incorrectly as I only get back a plot of 1 date and not the whole timeseries.

I read several SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584065/use-of-inverse-parameter-in-trans-new-scales-package) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130614/ggplot2-missing-labels-after-custom-scaling-of-axis), but no luck so far.

I know that a package called `bdscale` exists, but that hasn't been updated for over six years and the breaks / labels it creates are not what I need.

The outcome of using `scale_x_finance` should look like the plot from the **works** section. I wonder if someone has a clue of what I'm missing here.

I added some test data on the bottom of the question.

#### works

```
library(ggplot2)

# get the start date and the last days of the month for breaks and label positions
get_breaks <- function(x) {
  out <- c(1, which(ave(as.numeric(x),format(x,"%Y%m"), FUN = function(x) x == max(x)) == 1))
}

# use 1:nrow to be able to use scale_x_continuous
ggplot(test_data, aes(x = 1:nrow(test_data))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = close)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "date",
                     breaks = get_breaks(test_data$date),
                     labels = test_data$date[get_breaks(test_data$date)])
```

[image]

#### does not work

```
scale_x_finance <- function (...,
                             dates,
                             breaks = get_breaks(dates)){
  
  my_transformer <- function(dates, breaks = get_breaks(dates)) {
    
    transform <- function(dates) seq_along(dates) 
    inverse <- function(nums) dates[nums] 
    
    scales::trans_new(name = "date",
                      transform = transform,
                      inverse = inverse,
                      breaks = breaks,
                      domain = range(dates))
  }
  
  scale_x_continuous(name = "date",
                     trans = my_transformer(dates = dates, breaks = breaks),
                     ...)
}


ggplot(test_data, aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = close)) +
  scale_x_finance(dates = test_data$date)
```

[image]

data:

```
test_data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18995, 18996, 18997, 18998, 
                                               18999, 19002, 19003, 19004, 19005, 19006, 19010, 19011, 19012, 
                                               19013, 19016, 19017, 19018, 19019, 19020, 19023, 19024, 19025, 
                                               19026, 19027, 19030, 19031, 19032, 19033, 19034, 19037, 19038, 
                                               19039, 19040, 19041, 19045, 19046, 19047, 19048, 19051, 19052, 
                                               19053, 19054, 19055, 19058, 19059, 19060, 19061, 19062, 19065, 
                                               19066, 19067, 19068, 19069, 19072, 19073, 19074, 19075, 19076, 
                                               19079, 19080, 19081, 19082), class = "Date"), 
                            close = c(182.009995, 179.699997, 174.919998, 172, 172.169998, 172.190002, 175.080002, 
                                      175.529999, 172.190002, 173.070007, 169.800003, 166.229996, 164.509995, 
                                      162.410004, 161.619995, 159.779999, 159.690002, 159.220001, 170.330002, 
                                      174.779999, 174.610001, 175.839996, 172.899994, 172.389999, 171.660004, 
                                      174.830002, 176.279999, 172.119995, 168.639999, 168.880005, 172.789993, 
                                      172.550003, 168.880005, 167.300003, 164.320007, 160.070007, 162.740005, 
                                      164.850006, 165.119995, 163.199997, 166.559998, 166.229996, 163.169998, 
                                      159.300003, 157.440002, 162.949997, 158.520004, 154.729996, 150.619995, 
                                      155.089996, 159.589996, 160.619995, 163.979996, 165.380005, 168.820007, 
                                      170.210007, 174.070007, 174.720001, 175.600006, 178.960007, 177.770004, 
                                      174.610001)), row.names = c(NA, 62L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe this [conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/ggplot2/c/qrcvqy6TdzI) of Hadley Wickham helps?

Comment: @Quinten, Thanks for the input. I read that one, and the solved SO question that uses this conversation as input. Unfortunately that doesn't help with my issue. I can reverse the dates, not a problem. But using a kind of scale_x_continuous with dates that is. The automatic assumption that if you plot dates on the x-axis, that you want dates added when there is no Y value is the issue. I have a workaround, but that needs a wrapper function per plot type I want to make, instead of calling a "simple" scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in your `my_transformer` object. This needs to be able to take dates that are not present in your data and transform them appropriately. For example, when ggplot comes to calculate the plot limits, it may pass a vector of two dates that don't belong in your `dates` vector. The `transform` function will convert any vector of two dates into the vector `c(1, 2)`, which isn't what you want - you need arbitrary dates to be interpolated according to your `dates` vector.

A similar concept applies for the `inverse` function, which will have to handle arbitrary numbers and back-transform these into dates.

I think the easiest way to handle this is to ensure that dates are all treated numerically inside `my_transformer`, then retrospectively given labels at ghe rnd by the `scale_x_continuous` call.

So your transformer could be something like:

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_transformer <- function(dates) {
  dates <- as.numeric(dates)
  pos   <- seq_along(dates) - 1
  
  transform <- function(x) {
    if(all(is.na(x))) return(x)
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    y <- numeric(length(x))
    in_range <- x >= min(dates) & x <= max(dates)
    y[in_range] <- approx(dates, pos, x[in_range])$y
    y[x < min(dates)] <- x[x < min(dates)] - min(dates)
    y[x > max(dates)] <- x[x > max(dates)] - max(dates) + max(pos)
    y
  }
  
  inverse <- function(x) {
    if(all(is.na(x))) return(x)
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    y <- numeric(length(x))
    y[is.na(x)] <- NA
    in_range <- x >= 0 & x <= max(pos) & !is.na(x)
    y[in_range] <- approx(pos, dates, x[in_range])$y
    y[x < 0] <- x[x < 0] + min(dates)
    y[x > max(pos)] <- max(dates) + x[x > max(pos)] - max(pos)
    y
  }
  
    scales::trans_new(name = "date",
                      transform = transform,
                      inverse   = inverse)
}
```

And `scale_x_finance` would be something like this:

```r
scale_x_finance <- function (dates, ...) {
  
  scale_x_continuous(name = "date",  ..., 
                     trans = my_transformer(dates),
                     labels = ~ as.Date(.x, origin = "1970-01-01"))
}
```

So that your plot call is just:

```r
ggplot(test_data, aes(x = date, y = close)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = close)) +
  scale_x_finance(dates = test_data$date)
```

[image]

To demonstrate that gaps in the data simply remove space in the x axis (which seems to be the ultimate goal here), we can remove a week's worth of data and see that the dates on either side of the missing dates just move closer together:

```r
test_data <- test_data[-(25:31),]

ggplot(test_data, aes(x = date, y = close)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = close)) +
  scale_x_finance(dates = test_data$date)
```

[image]

Comment: Allen, thanks for this. It works on my dataset set aside for this question. Weirdly on a dataset with more records I get an error :-(. Error in y[in_range] <- approx(pos, dates, x[in_range])$y : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments. Testing a bit, the error starts when using 74 or more records. I'm going to debug to see if I can find where this comes from.

Comment: Found the issue. Breaks need to be set, otherwise in the ggplot adds 50 days to the limit in the `inverse` part and exceeds the in_range values, which creates a NA value as the last value going into the `approx` function. Of course when setting breaks, I have a plot, but now the labels are missing. Sometimes I wonder if ggplot creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @phiver it doesn't need breaks - just tweak to handle NA values - I have edited to handle NA values and tested on a year's worth of data.

Comment: And I managed to get my breaks looking like I want them. Is there any decent documentation somewhere about this part of ggplot internals or is it just a case of trial and error? The ggplot2 books don't go into this kind of detail.

Comment: @phiver not really. I’ve written ggplot packages that use a lot of the internals and it was mostly trial and error (beyond the _extending ggplot_ vignette). Even to answer this question, I had to use browser() extensively to find out how ggplot was using the trans object. I have learned tons just by answering questions here. Ultimately, this issue was more related to the trans object rather than ggplot internals.